# OpenCV SIFT descriptor keypoint radius

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I was digging into [OpenCV's implementation of SIFT descriptor extraction](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/nonfree/src/sift.cpp). I came upon some puzzling code to get the radius of the interest point neighborhood. Below is the annotated code, with variable names changed to be more descriptive:

```
// keep octave below 256 (255 is 1111 1111)
int octave = kpt.octave & 255;
// if octave is >= 128, ...????
octave = octave < 128 ? octave : (-128 | octave);
// 1/2^absval(octave)
float scale = octave >= 0 ? 1.0f/(1 << octave) : (float)(1 << -octave);
// multiply the point's radius by the calculated scale
float scl = kpt.size * 0.5f * scale;
// the constant sclFactor is 3 and has the following comment:
// determines the size of a single descriptor orientation histogram
float histWidth = sclFactor * scl;
// descWidth is the number of histograms on one side of the descriptor
// the long float is sqrt(2)
int radius = (int)(histWidth * 1.4142135623730951f * (descWidth + 1) * 0.5f);
```

I understand that this has something to do with converting to the scale from which the interest point was taken (I have read Lowe's paper), but I can't connect the dots to the code. Specifically, I don't understand the first 3 lines and last line.

I need to understand this to create a similar local point descriptor for motion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't understand the first 3 lines

Indeed this SIFT implementation *encodes* several values within the `KeyPoint` `octave` attribute. If you refer to the [line 439](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/173442bb2ecd527f1884d96d7327bff293f0c65a/modules/nonfree/src/sift.cpp#L439) you can see that:

```
kpt.octave = octv + (layer << 8) + (cvRound((xi + 0.5)*255) << 16);
```

Which means the octave is stored within the first byte block, the layer within the second byte block, etc.

So `kpt.octave & 255` (which can be found within the `unpackOctave` method) just masks out the keypoint octave to retrieve the effective octave value.

Also: this SIFT implementation uses a negative first octave (`int firstOctave = -1`) to work with an higher resolution image. Since the octave indices start at 0, a mapping is computed:

```
octave index = 0 => 255
octave index = 1 => 0
octave index = 2 => 1
...
```

This mapping is computed at [line 790](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/173442bb2ecd527f1884d96d7327bff293f0c65a/modules/nonfree/src/sift.cpp#L790):

```
kpt.octave = (kpt.octave & ~255) | ((kpt.octave + firstOctave) & 255);
```

Thus the second line above is just a way to map back these values:

```
octave = 255 => -1
octave = 0   => 0
octave = 1   => 1
..
```

And the third line is just a way to compute the scale, taking into account that negative octaves give a scale > 1, e.g `1 << -octave` gives 2 for `octave = -1` which means it doubles the size.

> [I don't understand] last line.

Basically it corresponds to the radius of a circle that wraps a squared patch of dimension `D`, hence the `sqrt(2)` and the division by 2. `D` is computed by multiplying:

- the keypoint scale,
- a magnification factor = 3,
- the width of descriptor histogram = 4, rounded up to the next integer (hence the +1)

Indeed you can find a detailed description within [vlfeat's SIFT implementation](https://github.com/vlfeat/vlfeat/blob/38a03e12daf50ee98633de06120834d0d1d87e23/vl/sift.c#L1948):

> The support of each spatial bin has an extension of SBP = 3sigma
>   pixels, where sigma is the scale of the keypoint.  Thus all the
>   bins together have a support SBP x NBP pixels wide. Since
>   weighting and interpolation of pixel is used, the support extends
>   by another half bin. Therefore, the support is a square window of
>   SBP x (NBP + 1) pixels. Finally, since the patch can be
>   arbitrarily rotated, we need to consider a window 2W += sqrt(2) x
>   SBP x (NBP + 1) pixels wide.

At last I greatly recommend you to refer to this [vlfeat SIFT documentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/sift.html).

Comment: Thank you for the detail explanation! Just one thing I don't really understand yet: Normally the keypoints should not be detected at the top most scale (remember the checking for extrema with 26 neighbors which are the pixels around and the neighbors in the next scales?) So why in here SIFT produced keypoint with scale of 2 (octave -1)?