# Keypoints detected by SIFT in openCV, its size is radius or diameter of relevant area?

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

[OpenCV SIFT descriptor keypoint radius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015995/opencv-sift-descriptor-keypoint-radius)
here deltheil answered as radius
But when I go to the documentation of OpenCV, it gives:

float cv::KeyPoint::size
diameter of the meaningful keypoint neighborhood

http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d29/classcv_1_1KeyPoint.html#a308006c9f963547a8cff61548ddd2ef2
so somehow confused...
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

That's two different things:

- The `size` attribute of `cv::KeyPoint` is the size of the blob determined by SIFT feature detector. The `size` is also known as `scale` and it can be derived from the smoothing level of the image. Not to forget: searching for keypoints at multiple scales is obtained by constructing the Gaussian scale-space. Each keypoint is described by a geometric frame of four parameters: the keypoint center coordinates `x` and `y`, its `scale` (originally it is the radius of the region, but OpenCV defines it as a diameter), and its `orientation` (an angle).
- On the other hand, the `radius` that is in question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015995/opencv-sift-descriptor-keypoint-radius) is a property of SIFT descriptor and it corresponds to a circle that wraps a squared patch (Gaussian window) of dimension `D`. By this window the algorithm is weighting or reducing the gradient contributions farther away from the descriptor center.

As it is also mentioned in the other question I greatly recommend you to refer to this [vlfeat SIFT documentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/sift.html).

Comment: thanks，@Kornel   I read it and got a question, what does in wang(z) the k mean?